# Custom entity extraction

Tags: 2013, search, powershell

I need help with custom entity extraction setting. I created an UTF-8, comma separated .csv file, script with the right dictionary (`Microsoft.UserDictionaries.EntityExtraction.Custom.Word.N`) and UNC path.

I'm trying to create it from the right server with the proper rights, search service working properly and still with any luck. The only interesting line in log is:

> Error Category: ResourceUnavailable    Target Object  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.ImportCustomExtractionDictionary  Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL

Environments:

1. SP2013E 15.0.4420.1017, single server inst., SQLS 11.0.5058, AD, Internet, domain
2. SP2013E 15.0.4571.1502, single server inst., SQLS 11.0.5058, AD, Internet, domain

The same file and the same script works on third environment

3. SP2013E 15.0.4569.1506, single server inst., SQLS 12.0.2000, AD, Internet, domain

[image]

I must overlook something pretty obvious I think.

[Csv screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the first few lines of your CSV file?

Comment: Sure, it is a test before production data will be used. Screenshot added.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see is maybe you need to run PowerShell elevated. My file is DeviceDictionary.csv. Here is my script:

```
#Setup Custom Entity Extraction Library
#http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219480(v=office.15).aspx

function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$path = Join-Path (Get-ScriptDirectory) DeviceDictionary.csv
$path = "\\" + $env:COMPUTERNAME + "\" + $path.Replace("C:\","C$\") 
Write-Host "Importing from:"  $path

$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
#Import-SPEnterpriseSearchCustomExtractionDictionary -SearchApplication $searchApp -Filename <Path> -DictionaryName <Dictionary name> 
Import-SPEnterpriseSearchCustomExtractionDictionary -SearchApplication $searchApp -Filename "$path"  -DictionaryName Microsoft.UserDictionaries.EntityExtraction.Custom.Word.1
```

Comment: Nice script, thank you, unfortunatelly, the same result (on that one machine)

Comment: Can you share the ULS logs while you try the import?

Comment: I can if you want to (has 10 MB, it is a testing machine so log is full of tested app errors), but the only interesting message is following I think: Failed to import custom dictionary Microsoft.UserDictionaries.EntityExtraction.Custom.Word.2. Failure: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Operators.TypedOperatorsBase '1' threw an exception..

Comment: Is your $searchApp returning correctly? Can you use the -Verbose parameter?

Comment: Yes, return the correct one. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D181A16282FEB65A!604&authkey=!AJl6AzUFR-gwTAQ&ithint=file%2clog [12 MB]

Comment: When you use verbose does PowerShell return any more info to the screen?

Comment: Tried it twice few minutes ago again, no more info in PS window or different error message :(

Comment: Off the record, get rid of the Search App and new one did not help either...

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Possibly the version has issues. Have you looked at later CUs that may solve "Search Issues". Or engage MSFT.

Comment: Should be this version only, other two inside our network works. I want to figure out why is acting like that, but even if I like mysteries, it takes a lot of time already. @Matthew McDermott thank you for your time

Comment: Are all your versions the same?

Comment: We have many different templates for SP13 using CloudShare, right now new template was added, again not working, with 15.0.4481.1005. Was 4420 before (also sooo old).

Answer (score 0):

Give to everyone possibility to read the file (Windows system policy).